# Filter object array based on string array "with partial match"

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects and want to filter it based on values of another string array and remove the objects that doesn't contain any of the strings.

I tried using split for the string array and search for each term in a forEach but it didn't work then tried the following which works as a filter but it filters for exact match not partial.

```js
var employees = [
  {"name": "zxc asd", "age":"30"},
  {"name": "asd", "age":"24"},
  {"name": "qwe", "age":"44"},
  {"name": "zxc", "age":"28"},
];

var keepNames = ["asd", "qwe"];

keepNames = keepNames.map(name => {
  return name.toLowerCase();
});


var filteredEmployees = employees.filter(emp => {
  return keepNames.indexOf(emp.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
});

console.log( filteredEmployees );
```

```
Expected Output[  
  {"name": "zxc asd", "age":"30"},
  {"name": "asd", "age":"24"},
  {"name": "qwe", "age":"44"}];

Actual Output [
  {"name": "asd", "age":"24"},
  {"name": "qwe", "age":"44"}]
```

I'd really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: btw, `removeNames` is misleading, becuase tis array has the keeping names.

Comment: yes i noticed after i posted the question, i used removeNames as i was trying the opposite at first then forgot to rename it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate the array with names `keep` as well and check the value.

```js
var employees = [{ name: "zxc asd", age: "30" }, { name: "asd", age: "24" }, { name: "qwe", age: "44" }, { name: "zxc", age: "28" }],
    keep = ["asd", "qwe"],
    filtered = employees.filter(({ name }) =>
        keep.some(n => name.toLowerCase().includes(n))
    );

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` uses `strict equality` so it won't match partially.

You can use `some` and `includes`

```js
var employees = [ {"name": "zxc asd", "age":"30"},{"name": "asd", "age":"24"},{"name": "qwe", "age":"44"},{"name": "zxc", "age":"28"},];
var filterBy = ["asd", "qwe"];

var filteredEmployees = employees.filter(emp => {
  return filterBy.some(v => emp.name.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()))
});

console.log(filteredEmployees);
```